# How can i use NGINX try_files without changing the browser location for the client?

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx `try_files` for Server-Side-Rendering. Since GET-parameters affect the resulting html, i want to use try_files to check if i have a prerendered version with the matching query string (file is saved at /posts/?page=5/index.html)

I have the following try_files statement in place:

`try_files $uri/$is_args$args/ $uri $uri/ @ssr;`

This works, but the client gets redirected to `www.page.com/posts/?page=5` which is including the slash of the subdirectory i have. This results in the browser getting a 404 in the end, because that post does not exist.

How can i use try_files like i did, but without actually redirecting the client? To be clear: I want to serve files from whereever with try_files, but not actually let the client know which file is served, thats none of the browsers business in my case.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Try: `try_files $uri/$is_args$args/index.html $uri $uri/ @ssr;`

Comment: This helped. Where can i find any documentation on this behavior?

Comment: Not everything is documented. You may check a few things at https://nginx.org/r/try_files